# Is there another, more formal, word for 'ride' in this circumstance?

Tags: fantasy, formatting, word-choice

Imagine a man standing by the highway, asking for a ride. Not a free ride like in hitchhiking, but a paid one. Is there another term for 'ride' that would better suit the situation here?

Setting is a fantasy one, where this type of travel is commonplace enough that language would have evolved in a way to have a formal term for this type of ride.

What would be some words that would be appropriate for this type of situation, both from the driver's perspective and the passenger's perspective?

Comment: This doesn't seem it will be applicable in other languages, so it seems to me that this question would be more at home at one of the channels about English (I'm guessing ELU). (And no, a comma or alternatively a dash would fit better.)

Comment: "Setting is a fantasy one, where this type of travel is commonplace enough that language would have evolved in a way to have a formal term for this type of ride." Are you asking for a real word that exists in the English language, or are you asking us to invent a word? The former would be on-topic on one of the English language SE sites; the latter would not be on-topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I strongly disagree with most migrate votes. Stack sites overlap. This is reality. Is this question absolutely unfit for this site? The place determines the type of specialist that will answer that. Especially for a [NEW CONTRIBUTOR], migration is extremely confusing. If we can salvage the Q, salvage it. If it is not fit here, close and let OP ask it in the other site.

Comment: And if they posted their question here, they want an answer from writers, not language scholars. [tag:word-choice] has over 300 questions. I think it is abundant clear by that number alone that this type of question belongs here. Call a Meta vote if one things it should be changed.

Comment: For example, a question about an anime can be posted to Anime&Manga. It can also posted to Science_Fiction&Fantasy, if genre-appropriate, or even to Movies&TV if it was broadcast or shown on the big screen. It all depends on what kind of specialzed POV the OP wants. Or where they landed first, in the case of new contributors.

Comment: We, as stack veterans and moderators, have a duty to guide other users into reaching the information they want and buidling a good reliable knowledge database. Swatting questions to **"where it might be more appropriate"** is, often, IMHO, against the spirit of the site.

Comment: RE migrating: One could play this game endlessly. "It doesn't belong on Worldbuilding because it's about English." Then on the English site someone says "It's not about English because it's about the language of a fantasy world." And the poor poster gets bounced back and forth instead of just getting an answer. In my humble opinion, give the question and the poster the benefit of the doubt. If it's clearly totally inapplicable, like Someone on the Physics site posts a question about Julius Caesar's military conquests, sure, bounce it. But if it's at all debatable, just let it be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written and read enough fantasy to get the gist of it.

Travelers want to join other travelers for safety. Bandits and monsters prowl the wilderness. Be it a farmer driving to and from the city to sell wares or a merchant caravan taking pilgrims and foot travelers along.

You don't need to invent a neologism. Unless your narrator is someone from that culture, you can use modern terms like **"rideshare."** Ambiance is important, but so is making your reader feel comfortable.

Is your traveler a warrior who can help defend the caravan? Then they might want to be **hired as an armed guard or escort**.

Are they a civilian just wanting some safety in exchange for coin? Then they are **booking passage** in the cart, carriage, or caravan.

Is the ride exclusive? Then they are **chartering the vessel**. This is often used for nautical vessels but it works on land-bound carriages as well.

They aren't paying? **Hitchhiking**.

You can use a neologism or a loan word from a fictional language, as long as you keep it consistent and repeat it often enough to justify it. Is the story about a long travel, a journey of discovery both within and without? Or is this ride a one-time thing? If it is the latter, don't bother with fancy words.

Remember, what really matters is the transformation the characters undergo during the story. Don't waste too much time on a word choice that doesn't matter for that transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a general, formal word for "ride". We usually refer to the type of transportation. Like, "George tried to catch a taxi" or "George waited for the train".

You could say "sought transportation" I suppose. But it's rare in real life for someone to seek transportation without knowing what kind he's after. Few people go to the train station thinking, "I might catch a train, or I might board an airplane."

If your fantasy world has some fantasy means of transportation, someone seeking a ride on one would likely refer to that specific means. Like, "George hailed a flying carpet."

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

No term for 'ride' would better suit the situation here.

Do you imagine your passenger asking not a free ride, but for a paid one?

'where this type of travel is commonplace enough that language would have evolved in a way to have a formal term for this type of ride' means exactly what in today's Emglish